# How to remove comma in the last line of sed address range?

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains a value on each line and it ends with a `,`. I want to remove the `,` in the last line of selected address range. I am able to achieve the following with `sed -n '1,3p' file | sed '$s/,$//'`, but is there a simpler way?

Example:

```
'12345',
'45322',
'90456',
'67895',
...
'34552',
```

Expected output:

```
'12345',
'45322',
'90456'
```

Comment: So you ask how to do something and you know how to do it?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm looking for a better solution, without invoking `sed` twice.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the lines after 3?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, I only need the lines in selected range (first 3 lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run both commands in one `sed` invocation, the one to remove the comma first:

```
$ cat input.txt
foo,
bar,
baz,
quux,
$ sed -n '3s/,$//; 1,3p; 3q' input.txt
foo,
bar,
baz
```

Note using the same line number for the `s///` as for the end of the range to print instead of `$`.

As an optimization, this also exits after printing the last line of the range instead of continuing to process the rest of the file (And do nothing with it).

Comment: if the first address is always `1`, then `sed '3{s/,$//; q}'`

Comment: If you are going to quit after 3 lines, why use `-n` and `p`?

Comment: @potong What if the actual range of lines doesn't start at 1?

Comment: @Shawn `sed '10,15!d' file` is the same as `sed -n '10,15p' file` in the example above there was nothing to be gained by using `sed -n '1,3p;3q' file` or even `sed -n 'p;3q' file` when `sed '3q' file` achieves the same result.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1,3{ 3s/,$//;p }' file
```

Output:

```
'12345',
'45322',
'90456'
```

Disadvantage: `3` must be entered twice.

Comment: That's not much of a disadvantage.... Roughly `sed '3s/,$//;3q' file`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '3!b;s/,$//;q' file`?